# How to update custom prebid version using the github?

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I went to download prebid modules from http://prebid.org/download and one of the new partners I was going to add doesn't work with the new versions yet when I download with the other partners.

So I went to use the github method (https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/blob/master/README.md) which I have used before in the past (late last year was the last time I did it this way). When I built it using `gulp build --modules=module1,module2,etc`, the build executed properly, except the version it showed in the prebid.js file was `/* prebid.js v1.25.0-pre */`. Prebid.com shows it is now up to 2.27 and you can't even get 1.25 from there if you tried.

I think this may be a result of it being at 1.25 late last year when I first did this. But I can't figure out how to update the files so it uses the current versions.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, the prebid team is generating that banner within their gulp file, the version is coming from the package.json file. When you pull the latest release from github, you will see the most up to date version in that built prebid.js file. If you don't there was likely a problem pulling in the latest version.

For the latest version, go the [releases page](https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/releases) and download the source for the latest release. run npm install. then run your gulp build command.

Example of how they are building the version from the gulp file:

```
var prebid = require('./package.json');
var dateString = 'Updated : ' + (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
var banner = '/* <%= prebid.name %> v<%= prebid.version %>\n' + dateString + ' */\n';
```